# How to generate a list of numbers in python

Tags: python

guys. I am now working on a python algorithm and I am new to python. I'd like to generate a list of numbers like `4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25...` with 2 `for` loops.

I've done some work to find some numbers and I am close to the result I want, **which is generate a list contains this numbers**

My code is here:

```
for x in range(0, 6, 1):
        start_ind = int(((x+3) * (x+2)) / 2 + 1)
        print("start index is ", [start_ind], x)
        start_node = node[start_ind]
        for y in range(0, x):
            ind = start_ind + y + 1
            ind_list = node[ind]
            index = [ind_list]
            print(index)
```

Node is a list:

```
node = ['n%d' % i for i in range(0, 36, 1)]
```

What I received from this code is:

```
start index is  [7] 1
['n8']
start index is  [11] 2
['n12']
['n13']
start index is  [16] 3
['n17']
['n18']
['n19']
start index is  [22] 4
['n23']
['n24']
['n25']
['n26']
start index is  [29] 5
['n30']
['n31']
['n32']
['n33']
['n34']
```

Comment: Do you want a list of numbers *like* that list or do you want exactly that list of numbers?  Do you know if can be generated by some algorithm or is it an arbitrary random list?

Comment: @JeffUK Jeff, what I want is a list with exact numbers. It would be `[4, 7, 8, 11, 12......]`

Comment: and how was that list generated?

Comment: @JeffUK My code could print them like the above, but I can't put them into a list.

Comment: So you're saying your algorithm works, you just need to know how to append these numbers to a list instead of printing them sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to give the same list: and I think it's much clearer what's happening!

```
val=4
result=[]
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(val,val+i):
       val = val+1
       result.append(j)
    val = j+3

print(result)
```

Comment: It works to find what I want. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do not think you need a loop for this, let alone two:

```
import numpy as np
dif = np.ones(100, dtype = np.int32)
dif[np.cumsum(np.arange(14))] = 3
(1+np.cumsum(dif)).tolist()
```

output

```
[4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ind_list = []
start_ind = 4
for x in range(0, 6):
        ind_list.append(start_ind)
        for y in range(1, x+1):
            ind_list.append(start_ind + y)
        start_ind = ind_list[len(ind_list)-1]+3
print(ind_list)
```

You could probably use this. the print function works fine, the list I assume works fairly well for the numbers provided. It appends the new number at the beginning of the loop, with a cotinually longer loop each time for x. I'm assuming the number sequence is 4, 4+3, 4+3+1, 4+3+1+3, 4+3+1+3+1, 4+3+1+3+1+1, 4+3+1+3+1+1+3, ....